# Update UIList when objects selected in 3D space

Tags: python

I have UIList populated with objects from particular collection from scene. Also i have custom_index, stored in scene as custom proeprty, like showed below:

```
layout.template_list("MATERIAL_UL_matslots_example", "",shelfCollection, 'objects', context.scene, "custom_index")
```

Where shelfCollection is my collection, custom_index, index pointing which record is highlighted(i suppose).
I wrote update function for custom_index, that when i select record on the UIList, it will be selected in 3D:

```
def update_func(self, context):
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    coll = bpy.data.collections["Shelf_Collection"]
    obj = coll.objects[context.scene.custom_index]
    obj.select_set(True)    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
```

And that works completly fine. The problem is in inverse order. I want to select object in 3D,and if that object belong to my particular collection, it should be selected in the UIList. How to handle object selection or some action corelated to that. I tried to use depsgraph_update_post but i couldnt find the way to run it properly.

Comment: Often in an update function `self`is used as a reference to the instance of the object with the property.  A setter and getter could  be used on the index property. if on for example `bpy.types.Collection` each collection can be displayed as a ui list.  If  setting a property with update in the update of another,  set with  `self.id_data["foo"] = value`  not `self.id_data.foo = value` to avoid firing its update.

Comment: I run the update func in debug, and i saw that in 'self' i had scene object. So that's right. But the answer is corelated to code quality right? Because i have no idea how to use setters and getters in terms of custom_index.